# A question about the relative sizes of Measurable and Supercompact Cardinal Numbers.

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is the least Supercompact Cardinal Number necessarily greater than the least Measurable Cardinal Number?

Comment: Lemma 20.16 of Jech's Millennium [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540440857) states that every supercompact $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th measurable cardinal. So it is definitely not the first one.

Comment: Why the vote to close? This seems a reasonable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supercompactness is much stronger than measurability:

Supercompactness of $\kappa$ states that for any $\mu$, we can find embeddings $j:V\to M$ of the universe of sets with $M$ transitive, critical point $\kappa$ and $M$ closed under $\mu$ sequences. This implies in particular that for any set $x\in V$, we can find one such embedding $j$ with $x\in M$ (that is to say, supercompact cardinals are strong cardinals. But in fact supercompactness is a significantly... ehm... stronger requirement than strongness).

In particular, given any non-principal $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\kappa$, we can assume that $\mathcal U\in M$. Standard reflection arguments (which are a direct consequence of the elementarity of $j$) give us that the set of measurable cardinals below $\kappa$ is stationary in $\kappa$, and much more. (So if $\kappa$ is strong, then it is the $\kappa$-th measurable cardinal, and is the $\kappa$-th cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\lambda$ is the $\lambda$-th measurable cardinal, etc.)

That said, there is a small subtlety: It is (widely?) expected that supercompactness is equiconsistent with strong compactness, and it is known since work on Magidor in the 70s that it is consistent that the first strongly compact cardinal is the first measurable. (Nevertheless, if there strongly compact cardinals at all, we can find inner models with many measurable cardinals, so Magidor's "identity crisis" theorem is not a result about the consistency strength of these assumptions.)

Comment: Some readers might benefit from the observation that this argument is a special case of a general fact: The first supercompact cardinal (if it exists) exceeds the first X-cardinal for any property X such that (1) X-cardinals exist and (2) X-ness of $\kappa$ is witnessed by a bounded initial part of the universe of sets. Thus, for example, if both supercompact and huge cardinals exist, then the first supercompact exceeds the first huge (despite the fact that hugeness has higher consistency strength than supercompactness).

Comment: Many thanks for all this information which makes the whole situation much clearer to me. I wonder why the least strongly compact cardinal is not necessarily greater than the least measurable cardinal since-in order to show that a cardinal is strongly compact-one has to look at sets of arbitrarily high rank in the set-theoretic hierarchy.  This is also just what one has to do in order to show that a cardinal is supercompact.